# (Time to Interactive) parameter is not showing anymore in Google Pagespeed Insights

Tags: google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

In this image [we can see that the "Time to Interactive" parameter is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCJPg.png), is it a new update or something else?

I have searched for it on the internet. I couldn't find any satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue - Time To Interactive metric removed from [Google PageSpeed Insights](https://pagespeed.web.dev/).

I just discovered in [this blog post from Feb 9, 2023](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/lighthouse-10-0/) that it was indeed removed from Lighthouse 10. I suspect but am not certain that Lighthouse 10 is the current version of the underlying tech that powers PageSpeed Insights.

From [the Lighthouse post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/lighthouse-10-0/):

> The venerable Time To Interactive (TTI) metric is being removed in
> Lighthouse 10, concluding the deprecation process started in
> Lighthouse 8...
>
> TTI marks a point in time, but the way it's defined makes it overly
> sensitive to outlier network requests and long tasks. Largest
> Contentful Paint (LCP) and Speed Index are usually better heuristics
> for...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the tool you are using has been updated and the "Time to Interactive" metric has been removed or replaced with another metric. In this case, you may need to check the documentation or support resources provided by the tool to understand the changes and how to interpret the new metrics.